# Java: many ways of casting a (long) Object to double

Tags: java, casting, numbers, double, long-integer

I have an `Object obj` that I know is actually a `long`.
In some Math code I need it as `double`.

Is it safe to directly cast it to double?

```
double x = (double)obj;
```

Or should I rather cast it first to long and then to double.

```
double x = (double)(long)obj;
```

I also found another (less readable) alternative:

```
double x = new Long((long)obj).doubleValue();
```

What are the dangers/implications of doing either?

**Solution Summary**:

- `obj` is a `Number` and not a `long`.
- Java 6 requires explicit casting, e.g.: `double x = ((Number)obj).doubleValue()`
- Java 7 has working cast magic: `double x = (long)obj`

For more details on the Java6/7 issue also read discussion of [TJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13855886/8986).

**Edit:** I did some quick tests. Both ways of casting (explicit/magic) have the same performance.

Comment: "I have an `Object obj` that I know is actually a `long`". It can't be.

Comment: My original code was `double x = (double)(long)obj;` which seemed to work fine. I haven't tried the other versions yet. I was just wondering what would be the best approach, since the double cast looked unnecessary to me. I now know that my `Object` is actually a `Number` that's why the cast does not fail.

Comment: Please do not post additional `parseDouble` answers. Useless parsing  just kill performance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As every primitive number in Java gets cast to its boxing type when an object is needed (in our case `Long`) and every boxed number is an instance of `Number` the safest way for doing so is:

```
final Object object = 0xdeadbeefL;
final double d = ((Number)object).doubleValue();
```

The danger here is, as always, that the `Object` we want to cast is not of type `Number` in which case you will get a `ClassCastException`. You may check the type of the object like

```
if(object instanceof Number) ...
```

if you like to prevent class cast exceptions and instead supply a default value like `0.0`. Also silently failing methods are not always a good idea.

Comment: I like this answer best. It shortly explains the boxing and I tried the `object instanceof Number` test via the debugger to see what is going on in my JVM. Thx!

Answer (score 7):

> I have an `Object obj` that I know is actually a `long`.

No, you don't. `long` is a primitive data type, and primitive types in Java are not objects. Note that there's a difference between the primitive type `long` and `java.lang.Long`, which is a wrapper class.

You cannot cast a `Long` (object) to a `long` (primitive). To get the `long` value out of a `Long`, call `longValue()` on it:

```
Long obj = ...;

long value = obj.longValue();
```

> Is it safe to directly cast it to `double`?

If it's actually a primitive `long`, then yes, you can cast that to a `double`. If it's a `Long` object, you don't need to cast, you can just call `doubleValue()` on it:

```
double x = obj.doubleValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need one cast, from Object to Long or long (which implicitly casts to Long then applies unboxing):

```
Object o = 5L;
double d = (long) o; //Apparently only works on Java 7+
//or
double d = (Long) o;
```

Comment: *"Long => double is not"* Works for me, presumably the `Long` gets auto-unboxed.

Comment: `Object o = 5L; double d = (double) o;` does not work. But `double d = (Long) o;` does. ;-)

Comment: @ assylias: I never said it did. :-) I said Long => double works. And it does, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple casting should work perfectly fine. This will be faster than going via the wrapper classes, getting string representation and then parsing to double, create new instance again using the long value - and more importantly, it's more readable.

```
double d = (double)15234451L;
```

Comment: Ehm, he said he has an 'Object' so there is no primitive `long` which can be casted to 'double'.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it to a `Long` (since the `Object` is **not** a `long` but a `Long`), and then cast the `Long` to a `double`:

```
double d = (double)(Long)obj;
```

For instance, this has the expected output of 2.6666666666666665:

```
public class CastDouble {
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        Object o = 15L;

        System.out.println(40 / (double)(Long)o);
    }
}
```

Comment: You only need one cast: `double d = (Long) obj;` or `double d = (long) obj;`

Comment: @assylias: I prefer the clarity, as the cast is there whether I write it or not. (And of course, in the above, I *do* need two casts. I could only rely on the implicit cast if I were assigning to a variable.) Also, `double d = (long)obj;` fails, you can't cast `Object` to `long`.

Comment: `Object o = 15L; double d = (long) o;` compiles and runs without exception.

Comment: @assylias: On what? It doesn't for me on Oracle's JDK 1.6: http://pastie.org/5519551

Comment: @Juve: Must be a Java 7 enhancement.