# Error while trying to get a Double value from HashMap String,Object fetched from Firebase

Tags: android, casting, hashmap, firebase, double

I don't know if this is a Firebase bug, Android bug or my fault. My issue is that I can't for some reasons get a Double value from Hashmap when fetching a child. Why? Because

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

Apparently every numeric value stored in a firebase json object gets returned from the HashMap as Long. The more strange thing? Using debugger, I actually found out that Android Studio knows they're kinda double/float, indeed if the value to fetch is 2.5, it prints out that the value of the hashmap for key "string" is 2.5.

When assigning this value to my double variable, it prints out the error above.

This is the code

```
final double[] rating = {0};
final int[] nRatings = {0};
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://MYAPP.firebaseio.com/reviews");
Query queryRef = ref.orderByChild("idCommented").equalTo(mId);
queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChild) {
        System.out.println(snapshot.getKey());

        Map map = (HashMap) snapshot.getValue();
        rating[0] += (double) map.get("noStars"); // This line causes error
        nRatings[0]++;

        mRatingBar.setRating((float)rating[0]/nRatings[0]);
    }
...
});
```

Still, if I should debug that iteration to check map value, it would print that Long cannot be cast to Double

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: The error message is very explicit: the value is a long (a whole number), so it can't be cast to a double. Make sure that you store the value as floats to begin with (i.e. store `1.0` instead of `1`). Or convert to a double when parsing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855786/java-many-ways-of-casting-a-long-object-to-double

Comment: What happens if you write `Map<String, Double> map = (HashMap<String, Double) snapshot.getValue();` instead of `Map map = (HashMap) snapshot.getValue();`? Does an error occur on that line instead?

Comment: roaster I cannot do that because the map must have the capability of storing other value types like strings. Frank the casting to Number and then doubleValue worked. The trouble was happening earlier even with numbers like `1.5`

Answer (score 2):

If you store a `float` into Firebase, it will be returned either as a `Double` or a `Long`.

This will work:

```
// ...
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChild) {

    Number priceN = (Number) snapshot.getValue(); // Long or Double
    float price = priceN.floatValue();

    // (do whatever you want with the float) ...

}
//...
```